# Problem with require while making a Ruby telegram bot

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot

I was doing a code in the app "Atom" and when I tried to run this code

```rb
require 'telegram_bot'

token = 'MY_TOKEN'

bot = TelegramBot.new(token: token)

bot.get_updates(fail_silently: true) do |message|
  puts "@#{message.from.username}: #{message.text}"
  command = message.get_command_for(bot)

  message.reply do |reply|
    case command
    when / start /i
      reply.text = 'Ciao, questo è un bot creato da @JustDavide per gli strike. Usami con /strike (Username) (motivo) (numero strike)'
    end
    puts "sending #{reply.text.inspect} to @#{message.from.username}"
    reply.send_with(bot)
  end
end
```

Obviously I made another file "Gemfile" putting

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'telegram_bot'
```

And when I use "Atom Runner" this error comes:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- telegram_bot (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/davidelao/telegram-bot/bot.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I started Ruby like 3 weeks ago, so I am not an expert

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
cd path/to/my_app
bundle install
```

Then try to run your code from console to see if error occurs

```
cd path/to/my_app
bundle exec ruby my_script_with_telegram.rb
```

if it is ok, then we need more information for your `Atom Runner` cause error lies in it

Answer (score 0):

I think that this gem is not installed. You can try these commands:

gem install telegram_bot

bundle install

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now.. I'm using Repl now not Atom, it was giving me some problems and now I'm ok with that site. Thanks to everyone anyway!